# Message in the Echo Area Disappear once Emacs is not idle

Tags: echo-area, message

I want the current *message* in the *Echo Area* to **keep showing up until the next *message* (which will also appear in the `*Messages*` buffer) is emitted**.

---

But how my Emacs does now is:

```bash
$ emacs -q
```

Use `M-x ielm` to enter the `*ielm*` buffer, and let Emacs to emit a *message*:

```lisp
ELISP> (message "This is a message.")
```

Then `"This is a message."` appears in the *Echo Area*.  
So far, so good, as long as I don't make Emacs execute any commands.

**But once Emacs is no longer idle, whether or not a new *message* is emitted, the `"This is a message."` in the *Echo Area* will disappear!**

For example, after I move the cursor, the current *message* will disappear, 
even though the `*Messages*` buffer indicates that there is no new *message*:

```
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
This is a message.
```

See, only two *message*s so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is low-level behavior that you cannot change (unless you modify Emacs's C sources and recompile it).

AFAICT, this is done in `src/keyboard.c`. There is a hook, `echo-area-clear-hook`, whose value is `nil`, but we can use it as a search string to find out where it would be run from if it were non-nil. The corresponding name in the C source is `Qecho_area_clear_hook` (that's a general convention for translating Emacs Lisp names to their equivalent C names - if the latter exist of course), so the search gives:

```
$ grep -n -e Qecho_area_clear_hook` src/*.c
keyboard.c:1350:      safe_run_hooks (Qecho_area_clear_hook);
keyboard.c:3121:      safe_run_hooks (Qecho_area_clear_hook);
keyboard.c:3174:    safe_run_hooks (Qecho_area_clear_hook);
...
```

There are three places where the hook is called, so presumably there are three places in the code where the echo area is cleared. The above output was obtained with up-to-date (as of 2023/03/11) upstream sources, but depending on the version, you might get different output (perhaps different line numbers, although I suspect you will still find three places).

---

With thanks to @Kaligule for providing them in a comment, here are the links to the currently released Emacs 28.2 sources for the three places identified above: [1](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/keyboard.c?h=emacs-28.2#n1361) [2](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/keyboard.c?h=emacs-28.2#n3061) [3](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/keyboard.c?h=emacs-28.2#n3114).

---

The three places are in the functions `read_char` (two places), one of which is presumably what's causing the clearing in the case you describe; and `command_loop_1` which seems to be more specialized. You probably should read the `read_char` function to understand what's going on.

Comment: Links to the three code occurrences in latest emacs release (28.2): [1](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/keyboard.c?h=emacs-28.2#n1361), [2](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/keyboard.c?h=emacs-28.2#n3061), [3](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/keyboard.c?h=emacs-28.2#n3114)

Comment: Thank you for providing the links!